# get HTTP_AF_REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: php, .net, apache, iis, web

I had a very important question 
How do you get HTTP_AF_REMOTE_ADDR 
What code and what version?

Run
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_AF_REMOTE_ADDR'];
error
Undefined index: HTTP_AF_REMOTE_ADDR -- at line 1

{
answered me;
my server limit
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many options:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_AF_REMOTE_ADDR'];
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_AF_REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Second is preferable.